# How to paginate a SectionList in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I have an array of object, which every object contain a section and a data;

```
const arr = [
  { section: "a", data: [1, 2] },
  { section: "b", data: [3, 4, 5, 6] },
  { section: "c", data: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] }
];
```

Now I want to paginate it.
I need to display 4 item in one page.

So it would be like:

```
[
  {page: 1, section: ['a', 'b'], data: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
  {page: 2, section: ['b', 'c'], data: [5, 6, 7, 8]}
  {page: 3, section: ['c'], data: [9, 10, 11, 12]}
  {page: 4, section: ['c'], data: [13]}
]
```

Any help, I tried many ways but still could not solve.

**My Efforts**

```
const arr = [
  { title: "a", data: [1, 2] },
  { title: "b", data: [3, 4, 5, 6] },
  { title: "c", data: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] }
];

let c = 0, na = [], ha = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  let ia = arr[i].data;
  for(let k = 0; k < ia.length; k++){
    na = [...na, [ arr[i].title, ia[k] ]];
    // na = [...na, {[c]: {section: arr[i].title, data: ia[k]}}]; c++;
  }
}

// console.log(JSON.stringify(na));
function chunk (arr, len) {

  var chunks = [], i = 0, n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }

  return chunks;
}

const resCh = chunk(na, 3);
console.log(resCh);

let finalArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i< resCh.length; i++){
  
  let nstd = resCh[i], finalObj = {};
  
  nstd.reduce( (t, s) => {
      
      if(t[0] === s[0]) {
        if(finalObj[t[0]]){
          
          finalObj = {
            ...finalObj,
            [t[0]]: [
              ...finalObj[t[0]],
              t[1], s[1]
            ]
          }
          
        }else {
          
          finalObj = {
            ...finalObj,
            [t[0]]: [t[1], s[1]]
          }
          
        }
        
      }else {
        if(finalObj[t[0]]){
          finalObj = {
            ...finalObj,
            [t[0]]: [
              ...finalObj[t[0]],
              t[1]
            ]
          }
        }else {
          finalObj = {
            ...finalObj,
            [t[0]]: [ t[1] ]
          }
        }
      }
      
      return s;
  });
  
  finalArr.push(finalObj);
}

console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: @SinanYaman I added my efforts

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
const arr = [
  { section: "a", data: [1, 2] },
  { section: "b", data: [3, 4, 5, 6] },
  { section: "c", data: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] }
];

const fillRange = (start, end) => {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((item, index) => start + index);
};

let result = [];
let j = 0
let maxData = Math.max(...arr.map(x => x.data).flat(2))

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   if (j === 0) j = i + 1;
   else j = j + 4;
   const finalData = fillRange(j, j + 3).filter(x => x <= maxData);
   let section = [];
   arr.forEach(val => {
      if(val.data.some(v => finalData.includes(v))) section.push(val.section);
   });
   let resObj = {page: i + 1, section: section, data: finalData}
   result.push(resObj)
}
console.log(result)
```

Explanation:

1. With `fillRange` function I create arrays of consecutive numbers 4 by 4 (like [1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8]...). These values have an upper bound = max value found in all `data` arrays (`fillRange(j, j + 3).filter(x => x <= maxData)`);
2. Find the `section` for which `data` includes these numbers;
3. Crete result object with all data found before and push it in `result` array.

Comment: thank you. I fount a shorter way. but still this dont solve my issue.